# How to draw permanent lines?

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw some horizontal lines in a chart according to given prices, and I want them to stay there permanently. But my script sets the line through an indicator, and when I go to other symbol and change the values of the indicator, obviously the lines change also in the previous ticker. So my question is, how can I draw lines in any ticker permanently?

I try this:

```
//@version=4
study ("Horiontal line", overlay=true)
hline(0.4, title="Top Line", color= color.yellow, linestyle= hline.style_dashed, linewidth = 1)
hline(0.6, title="Top Line", color= color.red, linestyle= hline.style_dashed, linewidth = 1)
hline(1, title="Top Line", color= color.purple, linestyle= hline.style_dashed, linewidth = 1)
plot(close)
```

But it builds as an indicator, it does not sets the lines permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make your lines permanent on your chart programmatically. That is only possible if you draw your lines manually.

As a workaround, you can check for the ticker id and set your desired value accordingly.

Here is a small example for you. It will draw a line at 16000 if the ticker id is `BINANCE:BTCBUSD`, a line at 1200 if the ticker id is `BINANCE:ETHBUSD` and a line at 666 if the ticker id is something else.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

ticker_1 = input.symbol("BINANCE:BTCBUSD", "Ticker 1")
value_1 = input.float(16000, "Value 1")
ticker_2 = input.symbol("BINANCE:ETHBUSD", "Ticker 2")
value_2 = input.float(1100, "Value 2")
default_value = input.float(666)

line_value = if (ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid) == ticker_1)
    value_1
else if (ticker.standard(syminfo.tickerid) == ticker_2)
    value_2
else
    default_value

var line = line.new(bar_index, line_value, bar_index + 1, line_value, extend=extend.both)
```